# Bullets and Numbering in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I'm looking for some comprehensive library for Silverlight on bullets/numbering. I've found a few, like [Vector Light's RTB control](http://www.vectorlight.net/controls/rich_textbox.aspx), but most are lacking extended features of bullets/numbering that word processing programs have, like having the First Line Indent of a great value than the Hanging Indent (e.g. first line indent is 1 inch and hanging indent is .5 inch). Another example is customizing the size of the bullet/number Anyone know of good libaries for this for Silverlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the ordered/unordered list controls explained in this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/OrderedList_Silverlight.aspx). You can extend its functionality to acheive what you intend to do. I have used it to show hierarchical data using nested lists and found it fairly easy to modify it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

that implementation works for read-only content only.

What if you need to apply bullets/numbering/indent to selected-text in a `RichTextBox`?
You have to programmatically find `Paragraph` elements inside selected-text and insert the corresponding character (bullet or number of tab) at the start of each `Paragraph` element.

Check out here for detailed explanation: http://www.codeding.com/?article=22